# Number of state entries needed before geth node is synced up with Ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ropsten, fast-sync

I am currently syncing a Geth node with the Ropsten network. Currently the download in the terminal show a neverending stream of `Imported new state entries`. I understand that I have to wait for all of them to sync before I can use the node in development purposes.

This leads to the question: What's the current number of state entries existing on Ropsten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My node just finished syncing. For anyone else who may be wondering this: At the time of this writing (2020-05-08) the state size is: `233101707`.

Answer (score 1):

On 2020-10-28 state size was `263121316`. So every month added around 5,500,000 items. Could be around 275 million end of 2020 and near 350 million by end of 2021.

Answer (score 1):

on 2021-09-01 state size was 300323737